# Cross Session Issue with CI and Opencart

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, opencart, session-cookies

I am facing a problem while accessing session on same domain same folder.
I am working on system which uses both CI and opencart systems.

For login I am using opencart login method and activating session and accessing them in CI. But inside CI controllers I am not able to read the sessions.

Please suggest me some techniques so that I can read sessions generated from opencart.

I can read them using this simple code
 print_r($_SESSION);

But in controller nothing works It shows me shows me CI sessions

Things I tried

1) No Cross domain issue

2) In core php file I can read session

3) In CI controller no able to read opencart session

Please refer screenshots for more details

http://awesomescreenshot.com/01b4f4oc2b

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b94f4old5

Comment: Codeigniter is MVC based frame work, where open cart is oop based frame work. The sessions in codeigniter are different. You will run in to lots of trouble if you mix them. I had same issue. It is best to keep them separate from each other. In my own opinion. Try not to think way open cart does there work and try to use codeigniter methods, Open Carts login not secure uses sha1 and salt. I have had same idea I am doing what open cart does but just all with codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with hooks.
In
$hook['pre_controller'][]

```
if ($_SESSION['customer_id'] != FALSE && !empty($_SESSION['customer_id'] && (int)$_SESSION['customer_id'] > 0)) {
  $this->session->set_session('customer', $_SESSION);
  session_unset();
}
```

To get back native sessions, in
$hook['post_controller'][]

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('customer') && ! empty($this->session->userdata('customer'))) {
  if (!$_SESSION) {
    session_start();
  }
  session_unset();
  $_SESSION = $this->session->userdata('customer');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('customer');
}
```

And that is for case of leaving CI app and using OC again. Not used, just writing loud. 
Disclaimer: not sure if would work or how would affect performance.